# Recover data after OS X reinstall

Tags: macos, data-recovery

I had to reinstall OS X. I was not succeeding to login to my Apple ID due to a server error, so I skipped that step and got a desktop -- but none of my data are visible.

Assuming that the data have not been destroyed (IMO they probably haven't), how can I get at them?

The old OS X was Mavericks. It reinstalled the original one, which is Mountain Lion. I don't think I asked it to wipe the volume.

df -- I had to email myself the output to post it. Not trying to be coy. Sorry. Here it is:

```
Filesystem    512-blocks     Used Available Capacity iused     ifree %iused    Mounted on
/dev/disk0s2   975425840 46603552 928310288     5% 5889442 116038786    5%   /
devfs                365      365         0   100%     632         0  100%   /dev
map -hosts             0        0         0   100%       0         0  100%   /net
map auto_home          0        0         0   100%       0         0  100%   /home
```

I have generally not used iCloud. I do have backups of my main work on another computer. But I don't have a backup of all the data that were on the computer -- it's not as important as the critical stuff, but I'd still like to get it.

Comment: Please add a lot of details like your system version, the `df` output (entered in Terminal. Do you have a backup drive/use iCloud. Have you done a "fresh install" (including wiping the volume)? etc.

Comment: @Allan it's there now.

Comment: One last thing...can you post the output of `ls /Users`  Do you see your original users there?  If so, take ownership of the directory so you can access everything:  `sudo chown -R username:wheel directoryname` of the directory you want.  Then you can use finder to cut/copy those files to your new account.

Comment: No, it's not there.  What I really wish I could do is go back in time to when I was setting up -- and enter my apple id.

Comment: @WilliamJockusch My almost default install of ML (including Xcode but **no** sleepimage: ~RAM size) is ~14 GB. Your install uses 23.9 GB. Maybe you remember how much data/apps you had. Additionally: AFAIK you can't "downgrade" Mavericks to Mountain Lion without wiping. So your data seems to be gone/lost

Comment: yeah, that's what I meant by does not look good